# Is it possible to deserialise either Json.Number or Json.String to a string without using a custom Converter?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am writing a service to consume JSON that I have no control over. One property in this JSON can either be a number or a string, so input can either look like:

```json
{"event_type":"status","value":"ok"}
```

or

```json
{"event_type":"status","value":-253}
```

I have a record type in my code which I want to deserialise into:

```cs
public record StatusMessage(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("event_type")] string EventType, 
    [property: JsonPropertyName("value")] string StatusValue)
```

As expected this works fine when I attempt the deserialise the Json.String variant but the Json.Number variant blows up with `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string.`.

I am aware that I can write a custom JsonConverter for StatusMessage but am wondering if there's any other way?

Comment: Does the type `object` work?

Comment: You know I never considered that @Progman, thank you!